# Multivariable calculus - squeeze theorem

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

My textbook says that because of
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} (x+y)^n = 0
$$

Iff $n>0$ we can conclude that

$$
\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} || \sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} (x+y)^\beta|| \leq \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} (x+y)^n = 0
$$

But I can't see why.

I've tried this

Let $(x,y) \neq (0,0), \beta \in \mathbb{R}$. So we have:
\begin{align*}
    &0 \leq |{\sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}| \leq 1 \\
    \Rightarrow \quad & 0 \leq  |{\sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \cdot |(x+y)^\beta}| \leq (x+y)^\beta \\
    \Rightarrow \quad & |{\sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} (x+y)^\beta} |\leq  (x+y)^\beta
\end{align*}

and then try to utilize squeeze theorem BUT second line is only true when $(x+y)^\beta >0$  which breaks (for example) when $x=-1, y=1, \beta = 1 $

Another thing that I thought was

$$
\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} (x+y)^\beta \\
= \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} (x+y)^\beta \\
= \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \cdot 0 = 0
$$

But that's only if $$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$ is defined

But the book does use $\leq$ and I didn't use it here, so I've not been able to figure out what does author means? Could you gimme any hint? am I seeing something wrong?

Comment: The very first limit that you wrote is also true if you put absolute values on it. So just add absolute values on the right-most expression in your second line.

Comment: For last question is enough, that $\sin$ is bounded.